# How can I make my code to repeat the same question in C

Tags: c, while-loop

I wanted to make my code to repeat the question 3 times, but it stops as soon as i give my first answer. My code is:

```
void initialiser_jeu(S_joueur tab_joueur[3])
{


    int i=0;
    int classe;
    while(i<3)
    {

        printf("Donnez la classe du joueur %d (tapez 1 pour nain, 2 pour elfe, 3 pour mage) :",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&classe);
        switch (classe)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("\n Vous avez choisi nain, vous disposez donc de 300 PV, 50 d'attaque et 1 de vitesse\n");
            tab_joueur[i].HP_MAX=300, tab_joueur[i].ATT=50, tab_joueur[i].vitesse=1, tab_joueur[i].exp=0,tab_joueur[i].soin=0,tab_joueur[i].niveau=1,tab_joueur[i].points=0,tab_joueur[i].cle=0;
            tab_joueur[i].HP = tab_joueur[i].HP_MAX;
            tab_joueur[i].ATT = tab_joueur[i].ATT_MAX;
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("\n Vous avez choisi elfe, vous disposez donc de 200 PV, 70 d'attaque et 2 de vitesse \n");
            tab_joueur[i].HP_MAX=200, tab_joueur[i].ATT=70, tab_joueur[i].vitesse=2, tab_joueur[i].exp=0,tab_joueur[i].soin=0,tab_joueur[i].niveau=1,tab_joueur[i].points=0,tab_joueur[i].cle=0;
            tab_joueur[i].HP = tab_joueur[i].HP_MAX;
            tab_joueur[i].ATT = tab_joueur[i].ATT_MAX;
            break;

        case 3:
            printf("\n Vous avez choisi mage, vous disposez donc de 200 pv, 50 d'attaque, 1 de vitesse et un sort de soin\n ");
            tab_joueur[i].HP_MAX=200, tab_joueur[i].ATT=50, tab_joueur[i].vitesse=1, tab_joueur[i].exp=0,tab_joueur[i].soin=1,tab_joueur[i].niveau=1,tab_joueur[i].points=0,tab_joueur[i].cle=0;
            tab_joueur[i].HP = tab_joueur[i].HP_MAX;
            tab_joueur[i].ATT = tab_joueur[i].ATT_MAX;
            break;
            i++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            tab_joueur[i].inventaire[j]=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *but it stops as soon as i give my first answer*. Please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please also include the exact input and output. It looks more like the `while` is an infinete loop rather than "it stops". Because there is no code that actually increments `i` since `break; i++` will never run the `i++`.

Comment: Replace your `while(i<3)` with `for (; i < 3; i += ((classe >= 1) && (classe <= 3)))` The seemingly complex iterator is to prevent `i` from being advanced unless `classe` is a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `scanf` is implemented correctly, if you write down at the comments, under this post, the input that you gave will be helpful.

So you haven't add `i++;` **above** every `break;`, so the one `i++` you have added in the third case is wrong, as @kaylum said.

To explain it a little bit further, if the program passes through `break;` it leaves the case, so the `i` statement never gets increased. Therefore, your program loops until you choose three times the third option. So every case should be in the form of:

```
        case 1:
             printf("\n Vous avez choisi nain, vous disposez donc de 300 PV, 50 d'attaque et 1 de vitesse\n");
             tab_joueur[i].HP_MAX=300, tab_joueur[i].ATT=50, tab_joueur[i].vitesse=1, tab_joueur[i].exp=0,tab_joueur[i].soin=0,tab_joueur[i].niveau=1,tab_joueur[i].points=0,tab_joueur[i].cle=0;
             tab_joueur[i].HP = tab_joueur[i].HP_MAX;
             tab_joueur[i].ATT = tab_joueur[i].ATT_MAX;
             i++; // here
             break;
```

Comment: OP says their code stops after they answer the first time which doesn't match with what you just explained.

Comment: the input is the problem at the question